# onCreate() missing from SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, oncreate

When I extend the SherlockFragmentActivity to my class, I don't find the onCreate() method in the list of the override/implement methods. Curiously, onDestroy() is present. Any suggestions guys?

Screenshot:
[image: This is the screenshot.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It extends FragmentActivity, which does have onCreate() to override

Answer (score 0):

That list does not show you ALL the possible override methods. Only the ones that apply to package SherlockFragmentActivty. ActionbarSherlock does override quite a few things, depending on a lot different situation.

If you minimize SHerlockFragmentActivty in the override list. You will see

- SherlockFragmeentActivty
- Watson
- FragmentActivty
- Activty
- etc

The one you need to look into is FragmentActivty that has the onCreate.

Comment: My `FragmentActivity` doesn't have it. Neither does `Activity`.